# Put an announcement out for someone

Tags: phrase-meaning

Let's say your nephew has gone missing inside a mall while being with you, because you are picking out an item in a jewellery shop. Then, you went to an announcement desk asking for some help, and the employee on post said:

> Ok, I'll **PUT an announcement out** for her.

What does this phrase mean? All I know are "to post an announcement" and "make an announcement", but this is new to my ear...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Put out* has many meanings, but one of them is "publish" (see "Put something out", meaning 4, [here](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+out)).

I would also use "make", but I would not use "post" for a spoken announcement, only for written or electronic text.

Comment: If sending something out on a public address, *broadcast* would be a good word too.

Comment: Do you both use this "put out" in announcing like what I've written? Or just the British.